# How to get an email when a computer is about to restart?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, restart

My work computer usually restarts once a week over night. This is done for security purposes. I don't know in advance when this could happen. Sometimes it may take even a month until the next restart.

My problem is that I have scripts running on my computer, so I would like to **get a notification whenever my computer is about to restart.** (I need to know when it restarts because I must log in back to my computer, otherwise the scripts won't run. Anyway . . . )

I'm trying to set `Windows Task Scheduler`   rule to send me an email whenever my computer is `about to restart`. However, it looks like the scheduler supports only time triggers. So, how can I do this ?

Is there any other way to get an email whenever my computer is about to get restarted ?

Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/855743/run-a-program-before-logoff-and-wait-for-finish

Comment: Thank you. I read that article. Now I have more questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728377/what-event-ids-precede-windows-7-restart

Comment: If you got the answer on superuser, then please close/delete this question here.