# What event ids precede Windows 7 restart?

Tags: windows-7, restart, event-id

I am looking for the major event ids that **precede** Windows 7 restart.

In my `event viewer` i could find only one unique event id that always preceds the restart: `7040`. Am I correct ? I looked up [this event](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc756386(v=WS.10).aspx) but I am not sure about it, the documentation says :

```
This event is written when an application causes the system to restart
```

Is this the only unique event  that **precedes** the restart ?

I need this to answer my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725287/how-to-get-an-email-when-a-computer-is-about-to-restart)